# Solution for listening to file once/download

Tags: file-io, paypal, download

I have energyshop.se which is a small webshop im doing for a customer. She sells various stuff but she has meditations on .mp3 and on discs. The customers can choose to buy:

- a disc which is then sent to their home address.
- one listening to one part of a meditation or one listening to all parts in a meditation
- some items are also available for download for another price.

So question is how do I solve this? We use PayPal at her site to make the payments and I know that after a payment I can redirect the users to a "thankyouforthepurhase"-page if I want to. That leads me to think that one option is to take the users to that page where they can download/listen, but I dont know how to "connect" the shopped item with the isplayed files to be downloaded and/or listene once too and how to limit this. I mean if the page is energyshop.se/thanks someone that have made the purchase can just copy that address and go straight there.

There is also a idea about codes in some way. If they make a purchase they get a code sent to them for download or listening, but how do I generate this code which has to be unique everytime and the password ha to change everytime someone has entered it so someone dont save the code as well.

Well im kinda out of ideas and not sure how to do this. I just wanna wrap this project up but I think I hve to solve this for her.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the solution depends on how much control (or security) she feels is required.  If all you need is a reasonable confidence that a user has paid, then you can be much more relaxed about the whole thing.

The 'thanks' page could easily provide the content in concert with the transaction id paypal will return - you can use this to control what is shown.  If you're not *too* worried about a 'listen-once' item being replayed, or 'download' being downloaded a bunch of times then you can avoid a bunch of edge-case stuff (where download fails or listen-once feed dies halfway, etc) and simply serve links to content based on the transaction.

If its abused then you can put effort into locking down content, serving mp3 streams from one-time links, tracking downloads in a database etc, but that will cost significantly more (in both time and server resources) so if you can, try simple first :)

Comment: Hi there Chris. First I wanna say some text was missing out and its energyshop.se if you was wondering. And as it it the security issue is not a huge deal, so a relaxed taking on it, it will be. Yes thats what I mean she has not very much knowledge in IT and just "want it done" but doesnt understand these things to consider, it will take too long time to make it secure so I will try the easy way (thankspage with id of paypal to show that content) first. When you write "in concert" is that just a saying (like together with the id) or is it method of doing this?

Comment: Just language, sorry about that :) Good luck.